# Interpreted standard library

Tags: programming-languages, interpreter, language-implementation

It's common for a programming language to come with a standard library implemented at least partly in the language itself.

In the case of an interpreted language, the obvious implementation is to read the library source files when the interpreter starts up,  but this runs into the messy but persistent problem of making sure the interpreter knows where to find those files even when both are moved around. It would be cleaner if they could be embedded in the interpreter itself, so there is just a single executable.

I can see a simple way to do this by just translating the library source files to C literal strings, but I'm curious as to whether there are any pitfalls I'm overlooking or refinements to the method.

So my question is, what existing interpreted languages attach library source files in the language itself, to the interpreter?

Comment: The problem you mention doesn't have to come up at all. Just don't move such things around, or update the language's equivalent of a module search path when you have to.

Comment: How is that moving things around any different from doing the same with a compiled language. Either you leave things in the default location the compiler/interp knows where to find them, or you're required to tell the compiler/interp where you put them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bytecode virtual machines often provide an answer to this: store the bytecode in files (*.pyc, *.rbc) and load the bytecoded versions of the libraries using a simpler mechanism.

Smalltalks do this by dumping the standard heap into a separate file called an "image".

As for single-file distribution, append the library file(s) to the end of the executable file, and include special logic for the interpreter to read from its binary and find a structure of those interpretable program data, or alternatively build the interpreter with a static inclusion of the program data.

Comment: Also, Lisp dialects typically make a similar form to pyc/rbc as "FASL"s (standing for "FASt Load"), which are either bytecode or some linkable dynamic binary format (so, not quite an object file, but more optimized than just bytecode).